# "\n" not working in text coming from mongo, but the concatened "\n" works

Tags: php, newline

basically, i'm sending one message to chat API

```
// $n->mensagem = Lembre-me, contrato 156051 \n  \n\n mensagem: \naaaaaa

$mensagem = $n->mensagem . " \n\n\naaaa";

app(Rocketchat::class)->sendMessage(
    $n->getAlvo(), 
    $mensagem
);
```

and the result impress is:

> Lembre-me, contrato 156051 \n  \n\n mensagem: \naaaaaa
>
> aaaa

only the concatened "\n" worked, how can i fix that?

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1ujj.png)

i tried to search for some responses in the internet and all i get is the nl2br but this don't work in my case

Comment: _'only the concatened "\n" worked'_ - that's the difference between _code_, and _data_. _'how can i fix that?'_ - by replacing the combination of the two characters backslash-followed-by-n in your data, with an actual line break.

Comment: `\n` is not a line break, it is an escape sequence that causes a string interpolation engine to replace those two characters with a literal line break character. This only happens when the string is interpolated, eg: when PHP reads your source code. The string in Mongo is already past this point and contains literal "backslash followed by an n" data, not line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

i just found the response, i don't know exactly why, but if you replace
'\n' by "\n" it will work

```
str_replace('\n', "\n", $n->mensagem);
```

doing this the message was printed like

> Lembre-me, contrato 156051
>
> mensagem: aaaaaa